# AngularJS: Sync Call the method in angular controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, synchronization

I want to call the method from the controller of the angularjs from the javascript method. So I used following function to call.

```
function ValidateLogin(data) {
    var currentUser = angular.element(document.getElementById('bdyIndex')).scope().SlateProject_GetCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser.rows.length > 0) {
      //doing the stuff
    }
}
```

Controller looks like following

```
  angular.module('indexApp', [])
    .controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http) {
          $scope.SlateProject_GetCurrentUser = function () {
              var db = app.db;
              db.transaction(function (tx) {
              tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM dbSlateProject WHERE ACTIVE = 1", [],
              function (tx, e) {
                  console.log('Fetched Active Slate Project!')
                  return e;
              },
              function (tx, e) {
                  alert(e.message);
              });
          });
      }
 });
```

So before getting the result from "SlateProject_GetCurrentUser", the if condition is executed. So it gives error as "Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined". How can we call the method by sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
  angular.module('indexApp', [])
.controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.SlateProject_GetCurrentUser = function (callback) {
          var db = app.db;
          db.transaction(function (tx) {
          tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM dbSlateProject WHERE ACTIVE = 1", [],
          function (tx, e) {
              console.log('Fetched Active Slate Project!')
              callback(tx) // is `tx` current user? replace it with current user if no
          },
          function (tx, e) {
              alert(e.message);
          });
      });
  }
 });
```

And you can access it like this:

```
function ValidateLogin(data) {
    var currentUser = angular.element(document.getElementById('bdyIndex')).scope().SlateProject_GetCurrentUser(function(currentUser){
       if (currentUser.rows.length > 0) {
         //doing the stuff
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Can you please explain this, and how can we pass arguments to this function?